# How to set radio button in angularjs with Object

Tags: angularjs

I have created radio buttons in angularjs using array of objects using ng-value and ng-model.

`

```
<div ng-controller="DemoController">
      <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedVal" ng-value="detail" name="test">
      </div>       
      {{selectedVal}}
  </div>
```

`
On selection of radio button model is populated with corresponding object value. But I am not sure how to initialize it using controller with object.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("DemoController",DemoController);
function DemoController($scope) {
    $scope.selectedVal={name:"Def",age:4} ;
    $scope.details=[{name:'Abc',age:2},{name:'Xyz',age:3},{name:'Def',age:4}];
  }
```

Comment: You should do `$scope.selectedVal=$scope.details[3];` to select the third value.

Comment: Are you sure the JsFiddle link is correct ?

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks but I have a use case, when Page is loading I am making two service call one to render radio buttons and another to populate radio button with already selected value (which is saved in database). If I implement solution which you have provided then I have to iterate complete array e.g. $scope.details in my example to find out index of that already selected value and initialize model with that value. Is there any other clear way to do it ?

Comment: @Ofiris Yes I noticed I mistakenly put another JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference the selected value from the details array instead of creating a new instance:

```
$scope.details = [{ name:'Abc', age:2 }, { name:'Xyz', age:3 }, { name:'Def', age:4 }];    
$scope.selectedVal = $scope.details[2];
```

This will select the last of the 3 radio buttons. Also if both `details` and `selectedVal` are defined within the same scope you should update your radio button as well, it's quite unclear why you referenced `selectedVal` from a `$parentScope`:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="selectedVal" ng-value="detail" name="test" />
```

And here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sb3krc8c/2/

Comment: Thanks @Darin but I have a use case, when Page is loading I am making two service call one to render radio buttons and another to populate radio button with already selected value (which is saved in database).  If I implement solution which you have provided then I have to iterate complete array e.g. $scope.details in my example to find out index of that already selected value and initialize model with that value. Is there any other clear way to do it ?